# How to find an element with some parts of href value ? (python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, element

I have some parts of value of href(ex. The href's query value) not a full value. In this case, what method is the best to select an element (for clicking, sending keys, etc) ?

I have tried with many ways but they do not work very well. Especially,  after getting html source, with 're' module, I extraced the full href. And then, I used 'webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='the full href']") But It results to 'NoSuchElementError'.
( I assume that the server continuously changes some parts of href)

Anyway,, what is the best method to find and select element only with some parts of href value ? 
(python3.6 / selenium module / PhantomJS)

Comment: `//a[contains(@href, "partial href text here")]` , this should work for you

Comment: @JAEWONJUNG  Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Href containing value

```
//a[contains(@href, 'part/of/href')]
```

Href that starts with value

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://start.of.href.')]
```

another option - to search not by href by itself, but `By.linkedText()` - possible in java with selenium, i'm not aware if possible in python

```
driver.findElement(By.linkedText("some linked text inside a attribute"));
```

Comment: I got an error message eventhough I followd your answer. selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

Comment: The full href : "http://m.kin.naver.com/mobile/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=8&amp;dirId=8020604&amp;docId=278621389&amp;qb=64yA6rWs7J247YWM66as7Ja07IOB6rCA7KCE66y4&amp;enc=utf8&amp;section=kin&amp;rank=1&amp;search_sort=0&amp;spq=0" (I got from webdriver.page_source)

Comment: I used part of href as '278621389' (docId). The error code line are following :  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, {}]".format('278621389')).click()

Comment: locator is correct, please ensure element is really present on the page (you can find element in chrome inspect elements using xPath or in console executing `$x("//a[contains(@href, 'part/of/href')]");`)

Comment: better to be 100% sure that par of href you are searching is really correct (after formatting) - created separate variable for it in debug purposes and ensure that element with such href is really visible on the page

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '{}']".format('278621389')).click()`

Comment: you missed `'` to wrap value with quotes in xpath

Comment: ensure that final href is totally equal to this: (with quotes and all other symbols) `//a[contains(@href, '278621389')]`

Comment: https://repl.it/JF5v/1 here is your code line) you missed quotes in xPath around `{}`

Comment: I have tried numerous methods with your advice and even I wrote another partial href keyword('mobile/qna'), and even with many forms(.format , directly typing, variable,,,) with caution of  ' ; " . But All tries failed. OTL....I'm going to be mad and tired. As I wrote in the original question upward, that even full href does not work. OTL

Comment: I did it! you're right(I guess, too). The codes are absolutely flawless. I just pulled the usb-connecter (for taking mobile IP to Desktop), and took a rest. And again, another mobile(New IP) connected, I restarted coding. It did work. Maybe continuous scrapping evokes server's defending(Just my guess...) Anyway, I appreciate you very very much. you deserve respect. thxs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='" + the_full_href + "']")
```

This will work if `the_full_href` is a variable

Answer (score 0):

Href containing value

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('partial href text here')
```